# PHP replace value in array with value from different array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, array1 with 408 rows and an array2 with 256 rows.

here is an saml example of array1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_127y4Gral
            [int_id] => 34213897
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 536870914
                    [1] => 536870914
                    [2] => 536870914
                    [3] => 536870914
                    [4] => 536870914
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_121y7
            [int_id] => 34213905
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 536870915
                    [1] => 536870915
                    [2] => 536870915
                    [3] => 536870915
                    [4] => 536870915
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_144y4Gral
            [int_id] => 34213921
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 536870918
                    [1] => 536870918
                    [2] => 536870918
                    [3] => 536870918
                    [4] => 536870918
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_132y2
            [int_id] => 34213921
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 536870914
                    [1] => 536870914
                    [2] => 536870914
                    [3] => 536870914
                    [4] => 536870914
                )
        )
)
```

and here is an saml example of array2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array([536870914] => 201920520)
    [1] => Array([536870914] => 201920528)
    [2] => Array([536870914] => 201920536)
    [3] => Array([536870914] => 201920544)
    [4] => Array([536870914] => 201920552)
    [5] => Array([536870915] => 201920560)
    [6] => Array([536870915] => 201920568)
    [7] => Array([536870915] => 201920576)
    [8] => Array([536870915] => 201920584)
    [9] => Array([536870915] => 201920592)
    [10] => Array([536870916] => 201928784)
    [11] => Array([536870916] => 201928792)
    [12] => Array([536870916] => 201928800)
    [13] => Array([536870916] => 201928808)
    [14] => Array([536870916] => 201928816)
    [15] => Array([536870917] => 201928824)
    [16] => Array([536870917] => 201928832)
    [17] => Array([536870917] => 201932808)
    [18] => Array([536870917] => 201932816)
    [19] => Array([536870917] => 201932824)
    [20] => Array([536870918] => 201920600)
    [21] => Array([536870918] => 201920608)
    [22] => Array([536870918] => 201920616)
    [23] => Array([536870918] => 201920624)
    [24] => Array([536870918] => 201920632)
)
```

what I am trying to figure out is how can i replace the dow_id values in array1 with the corresponding values from array2. All the dow_id values exist as ids in array2.

this is the output I am trying to achieve

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_127y4Gral
            [int_id] => 34213897
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 201920520
                    [1] => 201920528
                    [2] => 201920536
                    [3] => 201920544
                    [4] => 201920552
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_121y7
            [int_id] => 34213905
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 201920560
                    [1] => 201920568
                    [2] => 201920576
                    [3] => 201920584
                    [4] => 201920592
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_144y4Gral
            [int_id] => 34213921
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 201920600
                    [1] => 201920608
                    [2] => 201920616
                    [3] => 201920624
                    [4] => 201920632
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_132y2
            [int_id] => 34213854
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 201920520
                    [1] => 201920528
                    [2] => 201920536
                    [3] => 201920544
                    [4] => 201920552
                )
        )            
)
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You have 6 of these `536870914` in the first array but only 5 in the second.  How do you handle that.  In this case there is more in the first, but what about the reverse.  Essentially how do you know `536870914[6]` should be part of the one with only 5, do you just put it in there?

Comment: Sorray there is only 5 i adda one to many in the exampel in the first one I have edit it now

Comment: @AlexWelander - that's fine, but do you know 100% that they will be the same.  The problem is how do you correlate these if they are not perfect.  Maybe you just put it in there, which is fine if that is the way you want it.  I would also suggest combining these `536870914 => [201920520,201920528,...]` but without more context, who knows.

Comment: Can you change array2 to a different format?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yes I am 100% sure that they will be the same

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes I can change the format of array2 and array1

Comment: is `dow_id` always the same in the first array, just one not multiple ones.  Or another way is the value in that array always the same, not 2 "ids" ?  If so a simple loop should do, but I would change the structure of the second array to have the id from the first as a key and the values as an array.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I am going to give that a try thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really easily done with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). No need to change array formats:

```
foreach ($a1 as &$value) {
    $value['dow_id'] = array_column($a2, $value['dow_id'][0]);
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/j8vtM)

Answer (score 1):

If you change `$array2` to this structure:

```
$array2 = Array(536870914 => Array(201920520, 201920528, 201920536, 201920544, 201920552));
```

Then loop and replace with the array indexed by the current value:

```
foreach($array1 as &$values) {
    $values['dow_id'] = $array2[reset($values['dow_id')];   
}
```

If you change `$array2` to this structure:

```
$array2 = Array(201920520 => 536870914, 
                201920528 => 536870914, 
                201920536 => 536870914, 
                201920544 => 536870914, 
                536870914 => 536870914);
```

Then loop and extract the indexes where the value equals the current value:

```
foreach($array1 as &$values) {
    $values['dow_id'] = array_keys($values['dow_id'], reset($values['dow_id']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$a1 = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        'nodo' => 'N_127y4Gral',
        'int_id' => 34213897,
        'dow_id' => 
        array (
            0 => 536870914,
            1 => 536870914,
            2 => 536870914,
            3 => 536870914,
            4 => 536870914
        ),

    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        'nodo' => 'N_121y7',
        'int_id' => 34213905,
        'dow_id' => 
        array (
            0 => 536870915,
            1 => 536870915,
            2 => 536870915,
            3 => 536870915,
            4 => 536870915
        ),

    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        'nodo' => 'N_144y4Gral',
        'int_id' => 34213921,
        'dow_id' => 
        array (
            0 => 536870918,
            1 => 536870918,
            2 => 536870918,
            3 => 536870918,
            4 => 536870918
        ),

    ),
    3 => 
    array (
        'nodo' => 'N_132y2',
        'int_id' => 34213921,
        'dow_id' => 
        array (
            0 => 536870914,
            1 => 536870914,
            2 => 536870914,
            3 => 536870914,
            4 => 536870914
        ),

    )
);

$a2 = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        536870914 => 201920520
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        536870914 => 201920528
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
        536870914 => 201920536
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
        536870914 => 201920544
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
        536870914 => 201920552
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
        536870915 => 201920560
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
        536870915 => 201920568
    ),
    7 => 
    array (
        536870915 => 201920576
    ),
    8 => 
    array (
        536870915 => 201920584
    ),
    9 => 
    array (
        536870915 => 201920592
    ),
    10 => 
    array (
        536870916 => 201928784
    ),
    11 => 
    array (
        536870916 => 201928792
    ),
    12 => 
    array (
        536870916 => 201928800
    ),
    13 => 
    array (
        536870916 => 201928808
    ),
    14 => 
    array (
        536870916 => 201928816
    ),
    15 => 
    array (
        536870917 => 201928824
    ),
    16 => 
    array (
        536870917 => 201928832
    ),
    17 => 
    array (
        536870917 => 201932808
    ),
    18 => 
    array (
        536870917 => 201932816
    ),
    19 => 
    array (
        536870917 => 201932824
    ),
    20 => 
    array (
        536870918 => 201920600
    ),
    21 => 
    array (
        536870918 => 201920608
    ),
    22 => 
    array (
        536870918 => 201920616
    ),
    23 => 
    array (
        536870918 => 201920624
    ),
    24 => 
    array (
        536870918 => 201920632
    )
);
```

And the code (separate for readability)

```
$o = [];

#convert the structure of the second array
foreach($a2 as $k=>$v){
    #eg. $v = [536870914 => 201920520]
    $key = key($v); #get the first key 
    $o[$key][] = reset($v); #get the first value 
}

#code to replace (simple right), I am assuming that dow_id contains only 1 id (in duplicate)
foreach( $a1 as $k=>&$v){
    if(isset($o[$v['dow_id'][0]]))  $v['dow_id'] = $o[$v['dow_id'][0]];
}

print_r($a1);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_127y4Gral
            [int_id] => 34213897
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 201920520
                    [1] => 201920528
                    [2] => 201920536
                    [3] => 201920544
                    [4] => 201920552
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_121y7
            [int_id] => 34213905
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 201920560
                    [1] => 201920568
                    [2] => 201920576
                    [3] => 201920584
                    [4] => 201920592
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_144y4Gral
            [int_id] => 34213921
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 201920600
                    [1] => 201920608
                    [2] => 201920616
                    [3] => 201920624
                    [4] => 201920632
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_132y2
            [int_id] => 34213921
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 201920520
                    [1] => 201920528
                    [2] => 201920536
                    [3] => 201920544
                    [4] => 201920552
                )

        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/836ab0924d75cc88853930f01e6d03973dcae4cd)

PS. I converted your `print_r` output to `var_export`, var export is valid PHP syntax.  Print R is not. You can find the converter on my [website](http://artisticphoenix.com/2018/11/11/output-converter/).  I built it, it works great as long as the output hasn't been modified. Sorry if my website is a bit "janky" I never have motivation to work on it... lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [
    [

        'nodo'   => 'N_127y4Gral',
        'int_id' => 34213897,
        'dow_id' => [
            0 => 536870914,
            1 => 536870914,
            2 => 536870914,
            3 => 536870914,
            4 => 536870914,
        ]
    ],
    [

        'nodo'   => 'N_121y7',
        'int_id' => 34213905,
        'dow_id' => [
            0 => 536870915,
            1 => 536870915,
            2 => 536870915,
            3 => 536870915,
            4 => 536870915,
        ]
    ],
    [

        'nodo'   => 'N_144y4Gral',
        'int_id' => 34213921,
        'dow_id' => [
            0 => 536870918,
            1 => 536870918,
            2 => 536870918,
            3 => 536870918,
            4 => 536870918,
        ]
    ],
];

$childArray = [
    0  => [536870914 => 201920520],
    1  => [536870914 => 201920528],
    2  => [536870914 => 201920536],
    3  => [536870914 => 201920544],
    4  => [536870914 => 201920552],
    5  => [536870915 => 201920560],
    6  => [536870915 => 201920568],
    7  => [536870915 => 201920576],
    8  => [536870915 => 201920584],
    9  => [536870915 => 201920592],
    20 => [536870918 => 201920600],
    21 => [536870918 => 201920608],
    22 => [536870918 => 201920616],
    23 => [536870918 => 201920624],
    24 => [536870918 => 201920632],
];

/**
 * grouping
 * @param array $last
 * @return array
 */
function groupArray(array $last)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($last as $value) {
        $result[key($value)][] = current($value);
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
 * @param array $first
 * @param array $last
 * @return array
 */
function linkArray(array $first, array $last)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($first as $id => $fValue) {
        if (empty($fValue['dow_id'])) {
            continue;
        }
        $dow = [];
        foreach ($fValue['dow_id'] as $dowId => $dowValue) {
            $dow[$dowId] = array_shift($last[$dowValue]);
        }
        $result[$id] = [
            'nodo'   => $fValue['nodo'] ?? '',
            'int_id' => $fValue['int_id'] ?? 0,
            'dow_id' => $dow
        ];
    }
    return $result;
}

$result = linkArray($arr, groupArray($childArray));
print_r($result);
```

So we have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_127y4Gral
            [int_id] => 34213897
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 201920520
                    [1] => 201920528
                    [2] => 201920536
                    [3] => 201920544
                    [4] => 201920552
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_121y7
            [int_id] => 34213905
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 201920560
                    [1] => 201920568
                    [2] => 201920576
                    [3] => 201920584
                    [4] => 201920592
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nodo] => N_144y4Gral
            [int_id] => 34213921
            [dow_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 201920600
                    [1] => 201920608
                    [2] => 201920616
                    [3] => 201920624
                    [4] => 201920632
                )

        )

)
```

So even you have missed elements, you will receive null elements in the result array.
In both arrays you have duplicates. You should optimize their structure.